# How to Merge Two Specific Rows into One Row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, which has 1000+ rows and 20+ columns. I am trying to merge two specific rows into one row.

Here is the dataframe.

```
      Name     Document ID   .....   Text          Product
0     Sam      ABC-002-0789          Blah01...        A
1     Dave     ABC-002-1672          Blah02...        BG
2     Pete     BCC-076-7689          Blah03...        RT
:       :           :          :        :              :
n     Chris    WHD-012-1745(1)       Blah012...       B6
n+1   Chris    WHD-012-1745(2)       Blah022...       B6
:       :           :                   :             :
1800  Qutin    ABC-002-0789          Blah99...        Z9
```

I am trying to merge row n & n+1 into one row, these two rows are identical except for the text column. I would like to merge them together into one row, specific for the text column.

Here is the output that I want

```
      Name     Document ID   .....   Text          Product
0     Sam      ABC-002-0789          Blah01...        A
1     Dave     ABC-002-1672          Blah02...        BG
2     Pete     BCC-076-7689          Blah03...        RT
:       :           :          :        :             :
n     Chris    WHD-012-1745       Blah012 Blah022 ..  B6
:       :           :                   :             :
1799  Qutin    ABC-002-0789          Blah99...        Z9
```

I know that I can use groupby, apply, and join function to do that but I do not know how to target the rows that I want. I am wondering are there any faster ways to do it besides using groupby, apply, and join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first clean up the document ids:

```
df['DocumentID'] = df['DocumentID'].str.replace(r'\(\d\)', '', regex=True)
df
```

[image]

and then group by this document id (which will now have duplicates):

```
def concat_text(rows):
    row = rows.iloc[0]
    if len(rows) > 1:
        row['Text'] = " ".join(rows['Text'])
    return row

df.groupby('DocumentID').apply(concat_text).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Kris! It works perfectly fine!